# How to detect the location of taps in ios 7

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5, uigesturerecognizer

I have a view controller with half table view (bottom, 320x289)and half map view (top, 320,289). How can I detect location of tap?

Currently my code for the tap looks like this - when tapping, it hides the navigation bar so that the map gets some extra real estate. However, because it's not detecting location of the tap, when I tap on the tableview, I'm not able to segue into my table view controller.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(hideShowNavigation)];
tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

Ideally I would like to detect location of taps. If tapped at the top (if height <=289px), it hides navigation bar (or maybe even segue into a separate view controller where map is full screen). If tapped at the bottom (if height > 289px), then it pushes the segue into table view controller.

```
- (void) hideShowNavigation:(id)sender
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:!self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden];

    [self hidesBottomBarWhenPushed];
}
```

---

Here's the whole code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = YES;

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(hideShowNavigation:)];
        tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];    
}

- (void) hideShowNavigation:(id)sender
{
    CGPoint = [sender locationInView:self.view];
    CGFloat y = location.y;

    if(y<=289){
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:!self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden];

        [self hidesBottomBarWhenPushed];
    }
}
```

Comment: `CGPoint pt = [gRec locationInView:gRec.view];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your selector:

```
CGPoint location = [sender locationInView:self.view];
CGFloat x = location.x;
CGFloat y = location.y;
```

Comment: Ok thanks! I think the tap location is now detected. However, my problem is that when I tap, the tap goes directly into the @selector method (hideShowNavigation). Inside this method, I am not able to use the standard code written for the Table View, which is a segue into Table View Controller. In other words, how do I get the controller to push to Table View Controller with the standard code that's already written? Or do I have to write my own code for the new table view controller?

Comment: just updated the code for your review! thanks so much for your time!

Comment: Have you tried something like: 
`if(y<=289)
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:!self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden];

    [self hidesBottomBarWhenPushed];
}
else
{ 
 [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SegueToYourTableViewController" sender:self];
}`

Comment: This works great. I'm really new at this thing and wasn't familiar with performSegueWithIdentifier method...I still need a lot more practice!!